# catch paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste, coffeescript, paste

I need a catch copy & paste event. I have a example. But paste event fires 4 times. Why? I need a it a one time. Here is the code? Please help me?

```
$(function() {
  return $('#myform').bind('paste', function(e) {
    return alert("123");
  });
});
```

Comment: It only fires once in Safari 5.1… Here's a test page http://jsfiddle.net/u5LkE/

Comment: It fires once in firefox and chrome too

Comment: It's fires two times in Chromium for Ubuntu 11.04. Why event are different?

Comment: @Zeck Sounds like a bug in your browser. You should report it. (It's not a problem in Chrome 13 for Mac.)

Comment: Chromium is in a development browser - if you are experiencing issues, it's recommended that you file bugs. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: @Zeck Have you tried running this in any other browser, e.g. Firefox? If you experience it in Firefox, then it's likely an issue with your system. If not, it's safe to say that it's a Chromium issue.

Comment: Yes I'm. It's not CoffeeScript bug. It's Chromium and Firefox bug. I'm tried it on Firefox it's fires two times.

Comment: As @Rick's code shows, it's actually firing again when it blurs for the alert. If you use a `console.log` call it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm reported this bug to chromium developer team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which browser your experience four events being fired, but I've jus tested your code for myself and could not reproduce the behaviour. That being said, there are a few issues with your code as it is...

1. There is no need to `return` the jQuery object after binding the event.
2. There is no need to `return alert()`, since `alert` returns `undefined`.

Take a look at these changes:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').bind('paste', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
  });
});
```

See live: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/6CKxM/

Comment: Sorry I'm compiling it from CoffeeScript.

Comment: Hey I got it. It's bug of CoffeeScript.

Comment: If Coffeescript is generating that code, then you should file an issue : https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues

Comment: This is not a CoffeeScript bug. @Rick, please don't advise people to file issues on CoffeeScript when CoffeeScript is not causing their problems. Yes, CoffeeScript has implicit returns, which adds some noise to the JS output here. But those `return`s, while superfluous, have no effect whatsoever. (Only a return value of `false` would have any effect in a jQuery event callback, and `alert` returns nothing at all.)

Comment: If that's how you feel then I will gladly file an issue ticket against the generated code myself. 

I appreciate that you're trying to be helpful by explaining to me the use case for `return false` from a jQuery event callback, but I've definitely got that under control. 

Also, I welcome you to bring this commentary to me in person - considering you live in Cambridge and I live in Boston. Feel free to stop by the Bocoup loft @ 355 Congress St. anytime this week and we can debate the disservice of poorly formed transpiler code.

Comment: @Rick This is expected behavior of coffeescript, and for good reason.  (If you don't want this behavior, an explicit `return` on its own line prevents it.)  This is particularly beneficial in the case of defining anonymous one-line functions, but is almost always either what you want or unnecessary (but not problematic).  I would suggest using coffeescript before you bash one of its most useful features.